# How to set the object variable permanently in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, variables

I am trying to build an app with Flutter and Dart. Here, I want to retrieve data from my Firebase, and I was able to do so and put it in the replies variable in each Message object that I have as an array type in the Firebase by using a for loop. However, when I try to access the replies variable again, it becomes empty.

I tried using `setState`, but that just causes the replies variable to keep resetting. Why this is the case, and how can I fix it?

```
StreamBuilder<List<Message>> pickMessage(
      Stream<List<Message>> list, BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: list,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Something went wrong!');
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final message = snapshot.data!;
            for (var msg in message) {
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("messages").doc(msg.msgID).get().then((value){
                  msg.replies = value.get("replies");
              });
            }
```

Comment: Where are you specify the 'msg' variable in the codebase?

Comment: msg is just a temp variable i use fo iterating over message

Answer (score 0):

If You Need Some Variable to Initialize Once Put in Init Function or In Builder Function, outside the Scope of StreamBuilder, hope it helps

Comment: I am initializing it based on the data from Firebase though, so I do need the StreamBuilder, unless there is some other way to retrieve the data?

Comment: You Can Do so By Using  Provider package, Listening to the Change In the Data,

Comment: Because The Builder Function Builds More Times Than Expected Listening to Data Is a better Option In this Scenerio.